# Show that the boundary layers diffuse out from the plate with speed $\sqrt{\frac{\nu}{t}}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, continuum-mechanics, diffusion

I was wondering if somebody would be able to help me with this problem. I know how to solve it using dimension arguments but I'm unsure what is meant by transformation techniques. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

An infinite horizontal plate moves with speed U in its own plane relative to surrounding fluid. The plate is initially at rest relative to the fluid. The equations for $u(y,t)$ govern by:
$$\partial_t u = \nu \partial_y^2 u$$
with $u(0,t)=U$ and $u(y,0)=0$. Show using transformation techniques that the boundary layers diffuse out from the plate with speed $\sqrt{\frac{\nu}{t}}$.

Comment: Let $\eta =\frac{y}{2\sqrt{\nu t}}$, which turns the PDE into an ODE, and gives you the desired result. I think this is what you said you did. Alternatively, take the laplace transform of the PDE, which gives you a system of ODEs, which when solved give you the desired result.

Comment: Why do you get a system of ODEs for the Laplace transform? I denoted the Laplace transform of $U$ by $\tilde{U}$ and then I got $s\tilde{U}(y,s)=\nu\tilde{U_{yy}}(y,s)$, which has solution $\tilde{U}=Aexp(\sqrt{\frac{s}{v}y})+Bexp(-\sqrt{\frac{s}{v}y})$. I don't think this is correct however.

Comment: Why don't you think it's correct? It looks fine to me. Now just impose your (transformed) boundary conditions.

Comment: OK, so I get the initial/boundary conditions as $\tilde{U}(0,s)=\frac{U}{s}$ and $\tilde{U}(y,0)=0$, which gives me that $A+B=0$ and $A+B=\frac{U}{s}$? Now I'm really confused?

Comment: Also what is the inverse Laplace transform of $exp(\sqrt{\frac{s}{\nu}}y)?$

Comment: you also need a condition on the asymptotic behavior of the function, ie a far field condition, which says what happens as you get to large y. This makes the problem well posed. Generally, one has $U(\infty,t)=0$, which sets $A=0$,  in your notation. The Laplace transform you want is found in many tables, eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform

Comment: OK I think I'm close now. As you said $A=0$, which gives $B=\frac{U}{s}$. Taking the Inverse Laplace Transform of the function then gives $u(y,t)=U-Uerf(\frac{y}{2\sqrt{t\nu}})$. But how do I get that the boundary layers diffuse out from the plate with speed $\sqrt{\frac{\nu}{t}}$? Thanks for all your help by the way :)

Comment: @you've shown the length scale of the boundary layer is $2\sqrt{t\nu}$, so that it's time derivative gives you a speed, and the desired result. Also, no worries about the help, I'm glad you were able to work your way through this. Also, fyi, your question is sometimes referred to as Stokes' first problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation $$\partial_tu=\nu\partial^2_yu$$ is a diffusion equation in one dimension. Its Green's function in infinite space is
$$G(y,t)=\frac{\mathrm e^{-y^2/4\nu t}}{\sqrt{4\pi\nu t}}.$$
For $t=0$, we have $G(y,0)=\delta(y)$. Note that any solution of your equation depends linearly on $G$. Notice also that the constant function is also a solution of the diffusion equation. So let us consider the problem with $v=U-u$.
The boundary conditions for $v$ are $v(0,t)=0$, $v(y,0)=U$. Using the Green's function, we find that 
$$v(y,t)=\int_0^\infty v(x,0)G(y-x,t)\mathrm dx=U\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{4\nu t}}\right),$$
where $\operatorname{erf}(x)=\frac1{\sqrt\pi}\int_{-\infty}^x\mathrm e^{-z^2}\mathrm dz$. 
The velocity field is therefore given by
$$u(y,t)=U\left[1-\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{|y|}{\sqrt{4\nu t}}\right)\right].$$
It is a function of $y/\sqrt{\nu t}$ only. The layer with velocity $u_0$ is in one to one correspondence with $x_0=y_0/\sqrt{\nu t_0}=\text{constant}$. The layer with velocity $u_0$ moves at velocity $\mathrm dy/\mathrm dt$ that we obtain by derivating $x_0$ with respect to $t$.
$$\frac{\mathrm dx_0}{\mathrm dt}=0=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\nu t}}\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}-\frac{y}{2\sqrt{\nu t^3}}$$
from which we obtain
$$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}=\frac y{2t}=\frac{x_0}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\nu}{t}}.$$
From this result, we deduce that the boundary moving with velocity $\sqrt{\frac\nu t}$ is the one with $x_0=2$, which permits to understand the question since no definition of the moving boundary was given. Any layer with a certain fixed velocity move at a speed given by the last equation.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution using Laplace transforms

Using the definition of the Laplace transform:
$$\tilde{u}\left(y,s\right)=\int_{0}^{\infty}u\left(y,t\right)\exp\left(-st\right)dt$$
we can transform the PDE to an ODE:
$$s\tilde{u} - u\left(y,0\right)=\nu \frac{d^2\tilde{u}}{dy^2} \rightarrow \frac{d^2\tilde{u}}{dy^2}-\frac{s}{\nu}\tilde{u}=0$$
with transformed boundary conditions:
$$\tilde{u}\left(0,s\right)=\frac{U}{s}\quad \tilde{u}\left(\infty,s\right)=0$$

Taking a trial solution $\tilde{u}\left(y,s\right)=\exp\left(ky\right)$ and substituting into the ODE we find an equation for $k$:
$$k^2-\frac{s}{\nu}=0\rightarrow k=\pm\sqrt{\frac{s}{\nu}}$$
such that the general solution to the ODE is given by:
$$\tilde{u}\left(y,s\right)=A\exp\left(\sqrt{\frac{s}{\nu}}y\right)+B\exp\left(-\sqrt{\frac{s}{\nu}}y\right)$$

Applying the transformed boundary conditions yields $A=0$ and $B=\frac{U}{s}$ such that:
$$\tilde{u}\left(y,s\right)=\frac{U}{s}\exp\left(-\sqrt{\frac{s}{\nu}}y\right) \rightarrow u\left(y,t\right)=U\mathrm{erfc}\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{y}{\sqrt{\nu t}}\right)$$
where the inverse Laplace transform was taken from [here](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/auxiliary/inttrans/laplace7.pdf).

The implication of this solution is that the boundary layer grows as $\delta\left(t\right)=2\sqrt{\nu t}$ and the velocity with which it moves is:
$$v(t)=\frac{d\delta}{dt}=\sqrt{\frac{\nu}{t}}$$

## Solution using similarity arguments

For diffusion problems where a scalar field is initially uniform and the scalar quantity starts diffusing from one boundary to another boundary very far away (e.g. $u(\infty,t)=0$), the profiles of the scalar are similar at each time step differing only by a 'stretching factor'. If the profiles are scaled by the 'stretching factor', all profiles collapse onto the same curve known as a similarity solution. This is qualitatively shown in the following figure:

[image: profiles vs similarity solution]

Let's define a so-called similarity variable:
$$\eta=\frac{y}{\delta(t)}$$
where $y$ is scaled by a characteristic length scale $\delta(t)$ which is a function of time. This length scale is also known as the 'penetration length' and describes how far the momentum has diffused into the domain; we do not yet know what this length is. As the 'penetration length' can be assumed to increase with time, we can see this as the 'stretching factor' previously talked about.

Using:
$$\left.\frac{d\eta}{dy}\right|_t = \delta^{-1} \quad \left.\frac{d\eta}{dt}\right|_y = -y \delta^{-2} \frac{d\delta}{dt}=-\eta \delta^{-1} \frac{d\delta}{dt}$$

We use the chain rule on the diffusion equation to give:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial\eta}\left(\left.\frac{d\eta}{dt}\right|_y\right)=\nu \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial\eta} \left(\left.\frac{d\eta}{dy}\right|_t\right)^2$$
which transforms the PDE to an ODE:
$$\frac{d^2u}{d\eta^2} + \left(\frac{\delta}{\nu}\frac{d\delta}{dt}\right) \eta \frac{du}{d\eta} = 0$$
If truly a similarity solution, then $u$ is a function of only $\eta$; this is only the case if $\frac{\delta}{\nu} \frac{d\delta}{dt}=n$ where $n$ is a constant to be determined.

Since the PDE was transformed to a second-order ODE, the boundary and initial conditions are over-specified. However, when these are likewise transformed we see that in terms of $\eta$ we retrieve two unique boundary conditions:
$$u(0,t)=u(0)=U \quad u(\infty,t)=u(y,0)=u(\infty)=0$$
if we assume $\delta(0)=0$, i.e. at $t=0$ the momentum has not penetrated into the domain yet. This fully specifies the problem which indicates there is indeed a similarity solution possible.

Integrating the ODE we find:
$$u\left(\eta\right)=K_{2}+K_{1}\int_{0}^{\eta}\exp\left(-\frac{n}{2}\eta'^{2}\right)d\eta'$$
where $\eta'$ is a dummy integration variable. The unevaluated integral is related to the '[error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function)' and cannot be determined analytically; numerical approximations are [available](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Numerical_approximation) instead. However, it is known that:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\eta'^{2}\right)d\eta'=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$
which, if we define $n=2$, is used to apply the boundary conditions to give the solution:
$$\frac{u\left(\eta\right)}{U}=1-\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\eta}\exp\left(-\eta'^{2}\right)d\eta'$$

What remains is to determine the 'penetration length' $\delta(t)$:
$$\delta \frac{d\delta}{dt}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d\delta^2}{dt}=2\nu \rightarrow \delta(t)^2=4\nu t+K_3$$
Using the previously determined condition $\delta(0)=0$, we finally find that the 'penetration length' is:
$$\delta(t)=2\sqrt{\nu t}$$

The requested 'penetration velocity' is again found as:
$$v(t)=\frac{d\delta}{dt}=\sqrt{\frac{\nu}{t}}$$

Note: In transport phenomena, the 'penetration length' is usually defined as $\tilde{\delta}(t)=\sqrt{\pi\nu t}$. This can be found from the above analysis by taking the derivative at $y=0$:
$$\frac{du}{dy}(0,t) = -\frac{U}{\tilde{\delta}(t)}$$
which implies that a tangent at $y=0$ will cross the $y$-axis at $\tilde{\delta}(t)$. From the analysis we determine:
$$\frac{du}{dy}(0,t) = \frac{du}{d\eta}(0,t) \frac{d\eta}{dy} = -\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}U\delta^{-1}=-\frac{U}{\sqrt{\pi\nu t}}$$
which shows that indeed $\tilde{\delta}(t)=\sqrt{\pi\nu t}$.